# IntelliJ IDEA Java code style: Space between Annotation and Enum

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, jetbrains-ide, autoformatting

How to add space between `)` and `Enum` name?

I want to see this:

```
enum SampleEnum {
    @Annotation("1") ONE,
    @Annotation("2") TWO,
    @Annotation THREE
}
```

This is how auto-formatting works:

```
enum SampleEnum {
    @Annotation("1")ONE,
    @Annotation("2")TWO,
    @Annotation THREE
}
```

Don't want to use `@formatter:off / on`

*UPDATE:*

I added an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170457

Answer (score 0):

The settings for auto formatting code are grabbed from the settings for "Code Style." These settings can be found at:

`File - Settings - Editor - Code Style - Java`

The setting your looking for is probably under the "Spaces" tab

Hopefully this fixes your problem.

Alternatively you can look through the IDEA add on repository for code style add-ons:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search/idea?correctionAllowed=true&search=code+style

Comment: I think your in trouble then. You can, of course, write the custom code or look for that specific add-on but it might just be faster to accept that issue or at the end of a project fuzzy replace @Annotation("<>") with @Annotation("<>")_.